# I can not drag the UISegment to my Controller's NavigationBar in Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I got an issue, I can not drag a UISegmentControl to my Controller's NavigationBar, someone can help me?

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Why I can not drag the UISegment to my navigation Bar?

---

**EDIT**

This is the Document Outline of my Controller:

[image]

Comment: Can you share me the Document Outline to us?

Comment: @aircraft whats mean of Document Outline?

Comment: Click the left bottom button of your first image you can see it. snapshot the controller's outline to us.

Comment: did you add navigationbar to your ViewController? I can't see the bar in your screenshot & that is the cause.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I was embed in a NavigationController.

Comment: yes...but you have to add in your viewcontroller, becuase default only available for first child of Navigation controller, for later viewcontroller you have to add.  Navigation controller only manage the stacks of view

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller do not have the Navigation Item, so you can not add widget on it.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

So you should drag the navigation item at first.

[image]

Then drag the UISegmentedControl.